# Dymola initialization iteration variables

Tags: iteration, modelica, dymola

I am using Dymola with the following flags for debugging initialization failures:

```
Advanced.FMI.GenerateModelDescriptionInterface2 = true;
Advanced.GenerateVariableDependencies = true;
Advanced.LogNonLinearIterationVariables = true;
Advanced.LogStartValuesForIterationVariables = true;
Advanced.TranslationInCommandLog = true;
LogStateSelection = true;
```

It seems that the `dsmodelIterationSelect.mof` file lists the iteration variables for the simulation, but according to the translation log a different set of iteration variables is used during initialization. Is that understanding correct? And is there an easy way to print a list of all iteration variables that are used for initialization? Are IVs for initialization logged anywhere besides translation log and `dsmodel.mof`?

Comment: You also have them in the dslog.txt if the initialization fails. 
Since each non-linear system is initialized one by one (at least in the latter versions of Dymola I have used), you will only get the list of IVs of the system whose initialization fails.
If by the time you have gained any information on the usage of dsmodelIterationSelect.mof, please share your understanding. :)

Comment: To have them in the dslog.txt you have to activate `Detailed logging of failed nonlinear solutions`in the `Debug`tab of `Simulation Setup` (in the most recent versions of Dymola).